# добавление полей в SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp

Требуется вывести пользователей в выпадающий список. 
Использую :

```
SelectList users = new SelectList(db.Users,"Id","Name");
ViewBag.Users = users;
```

Как добавить фамилию (`FirstName`) и отчество (`Patronymic`)?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так, на память написал, но смысл должен быть понятен.

```
var users = db.Users.Select(s=> new {Id=s.id, Name= s.FirstName + " " + s.Patronymic}).ToList(); 
model.Users = new SelectList(users, "ID", "Name");
```